# undefined method 'engines' for Rails::Engine::Railties:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been setting up ruby on rails on my mac - I'm learning (I guess we all are) - I run rails and go to the site where the app is and see the following error.

**undefined method 'engines' for Rails::Engine::Railties:Class**

The app was running fine until I bundle installed the dependant gems (I think I may have updated them).

1. How do I read this error so I know what actually is wrong.
2. If I have to define the method, how do I do that - what with and where?

Thanks in advance,

Dan

Comment: https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx/issues/683, Try running `bundle update joiner`